# Rails 3.0.7 with ruby 1.9.2 fixtures with :belongs_to and :has_many gives "table users has no column named posts"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, fixtures

I can't get these fixtures to load and I don't know why. After spending a few hours on the problem and starting to seriously question my grasp of reality. So I turn here in hope of someone pointing out the error with hopefully minimal ridicule.

I have tried doing it the same way as the [api-docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Fixtures.html) describe and combining with the [authlogic](http://rdoc.info/github/binarylogic/authlogic/master/Authlogic/TestCase) documentation. None of the posts I could find here on SO were of any help either.

Using ruby 1.9.2-p180

## users.yml

```
one:
  id: 0
  username: testuserone
  email: whatever@whatever.com
  password_salt: <%= salt = Authlogic::Random.hex_token %>
  crypted_password: <%= Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512.encrypt("benrocks" + salt) %>
  persistence_token: <%= Authlogic::Random.hex_token %>
  posts: one, two

two:
  id: 1
  username: testusertwo
  email: test@gmail.com
  password_salt: <%= salt = Authlogic::Random.hex_token %>
  crypted_password: <%= Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512.encrypt("benrocks" + salt) %>
  persistence_token: <%= Authlogic::Random.hex_token %>
  posts: one, two, valid_post
```

## posts.yml

```
one:
  title: First valid Awesome post
  content: Clearly awesome content
  user: one

two:
  title: Second valid Awesome post
  content: Clearly more awesome content
  user: one

valid_post:
  title: Awesome post
  content: Clearly awesome content
  user: one

empty_post:
  title: 
  content: 
  user: one
```

## schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110527132832) do

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

## post.rb - model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_reader :per_page
  @@per_page = 3
  default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC' 
  validates :title, :presence => true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

## user.rb - model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  acts_as_authentic

  has_many :posts
end
```

## rake db:fixtures:load gives

rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: table users has no column named posts: INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "username", "email", "password_salt", "crypted_password", "persistence_token", "posts", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (0, 'testuserone', 'whatever@whatever.com', 'ce407b78abcdf7ef7a179f2ef3c4452892411fe0705fc363623f669c420204c3ceb452167a2470ef737d2d8eae6ff0eca75e1eae2f7965d2eeaf2262a3ce61df', 'ecd509731f30ed38442d4f0e6c0da81e7e747e5ded086be96a3b45b896cde0b99b314d187b1f0011ba5c6a1f661c9748fd20ac11332a413b8046ee9738167cc2', '784c46f5e1f8218592e5f46a00111a00281e53a25a36133c17de9e31f3a1e99fe8c45fc5c327b87f32dff6147b56337b900c6a1342329479dfd1c372d700a37c', 'one, two', '2011-05-28 13:28:44', '2011-05-28 13:28:44')

## Gems in use

source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'nifty-generators'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'faker'
gem "mocha", :group => :test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out it started working either when I migrated the test db or when I gave all posts names that differed from users like :user_one, :user_two

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used fixtures for a long time, but I don't think you need to describe the association in users.yml since you already do that in posts.yml. Try removing those lines.

Comment: The fixtures load but there doesn't seem to be any association between the post and user.

Post.first
 => #<Post id: 298486374, title: "Second valid Awesome post", content: "Clearly more awesome content", created_at: "2011-05-28 14:22:14", updated_at: "2011-05-28 14:22:14", user_id: 980190962> 
User.first => #<User id: 0 ... ...
User.first.posts => []