# Rails: Getting "Table events has no column named user_id" error on all tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All my tests are giving errors. I tried to sort for a good while, to no avail. They are similar to the following:

```
30) Error:                                                                                                     
UserTest#test_a_user_should_enter_a_first_name:                                                                 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table events has no column named user_id: INSERT INTO "ev
ents" ("text", "event_start", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', '2012-08-10', 20790
7133, '2014-04-02 03:43:47', '2014-04-02 03:43:47', 980190962)                                                  


 31) Error:                                                                                                     
UserTest#test_a_user_should_enter_a_last_name:                                                                  
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table events has no column named user_id: INSERT INTO "ev
ents" ("text", "event_start", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', '2012-08-10', 20790
7133, '2014-04-02 03:43:47', '2014-04-02 03:43:47', 980190962)                                                  


 32) Error:                                                                                                     
UserTest#test_a_user_should_have_a_profile_name_without_spaces:                                                 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: table events has no column named user_id: INSERT INTO "ev
ents" ("text", "event_start", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', '2012-08-10', 20790
7133, '2014-04-02 03:43:47', '2014-04-02 03:43:47', 980190962)
```

I should mention that the app itself is working perfectly fine. Various things depend on the user_id attribute, and they run.

As for tests, I looked around and found a mention of `Check your fixtures file! Whenever I'd rename columns, I'd usually forget to tweak my fixtures to match. This causes an error on every single test, just like you're seeing.` [Error in all unit and functional tests after altering column names of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065752/error-in-all-unit-and-functional-tests-after-altering-column-names-of-a-table) Not sure if that applies to my issue though. As you can see, it says events already has a user_id. I don't quite get how all the tests are failing, even seemingly unrelated ones. That's what's throwing me off.

My section of GitHub: https://github.com/attatae/and_silva

Also looked at this: [Rails 3.0.7 with ruby 1.9.2 fixtures with :belongs_to and :has_many gives "table users has no column named posts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161988/rails-3-0-7-with-ruby-1-9-2-fixtures-with-belongs-to-and-has-many-gives-table)

Do I need to insert user_id into xxyynum_create_events.rb?
`ie integer :user_id` under `create table :events do |t|`

Other things I tried:
rake db:test:prepare
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
dropping then recreating the db

All help very appreciated.

**Update**===============

After posting, I changed my [bignum]_create_events.rb to look like so:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.datetime :time_begin 
      t.string :location
      t.date :event_start
      t.text :text
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :user 

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I then tried doing `bundle exec rake db:reset && bundle exec rake db:populate && bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` but received an error `"Don't know how to build task 'db:populate'.

So I tried `bundle exec rake db:drop && bundle exec rake db:create && bundle exec rake db:migrate && bundle exec db:test:prepare` instead, but it said 
`no such table: events: ALTER TABLE "events" ADD "address" varchar(255)C:/Rails Projects/Git pull/and_silva/db/migrate/20140329045140_add_address_to_event.rb:3:in`change'`

Next I went into dev and test sandboxes, and they both said that `Event(Table doesn't exist)`.

Then I tried running rails s just to make sure I was even trying to fix the right program, since my application was running earlier just fine, apparently with no user_id aspect in events.

The site said `Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.` I tried running rake db:migrate instead. Then it said:

```
==  AddAddressToEvent: migrating ==============================================
-- add_column(:events, :address, :string)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: events: ALTER TABLE "events" ADD "address" varchar(255)C:/Rails Projects/Git pull/and_silva/db/migrate/20140329045140_add_address_to_event.rb:3:in *change'
C:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Then I ran rake and got the same exact errors as before for 32 tests.

I ran rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development and then got the same AQLite3 [...] ALTER TABLE error.

Answer (score 8):

**Check fixtures and see if they are mis-matched to your schema.**

I had a similar problem. My fixtures had an old value even though I removed it from my db. So, Rails test was loading fixtures and they were not the same as my updated db.

Answer (score 4):

Just type `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`.It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your /db/* schema and migration files I can't see user_id defined for events table anywhere.

And I found it was [here](https://github.com/attatae/and_silva/commit/d63ca729271846ad83922266c1e86eba253b6584#diff-faca9baef4b08f66fd6bec9cc4d91a11) on `db/schema.rb`

Fix it and try:
`bundle exec rake db:reset && bundle exec rake db:populate && bundle exec rake db:test:prepare`

If it'll not be enough than you should get error message that some other `rake` tasks are required.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Rails and didn't quite understand the suggestion. If you did find it, the tests still do not run. The errors shown above are from me adding user_id to create_events migration. As I edited my main question to reflect, the app runs, so apart from that, it isn't yet too clear where to make changes. Do you mean add `t.integer :user_id` to create_events migration?

Comment: I checked it on your github repo and at current version there is no user_id @events table. I found it was on some previous. Check the link above to see diff for changes you've made. If your app runs fine and the tests not than probably because your db versions for test and dev. are not the same.

Comment: You can check manually what's there. Run `rails c test --sandbox` and `rails c dev --sandbox` type `Event` on both and compare.

Comment: Hi pawel7318, I did as you mentioned. However, my app said "Don't know how to build task 'db:populate." Is there another alternative? And I get other errors. My app dev and test areas did not have event tables, apparently.

Comment: `db:populate` is to fill your db. with sample data. If you don't have it than you don't need it. We can move to chat if you wish. Just create a channel and invite me there.

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to make a chat room. I went to the chat page, but it is not exactly intuitive https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms. And then maybe you meant IRC. I would like very much like to chat, perhaps you have a link you can point me to, today or tomorrow? In any case, I ran without "populate," and application works again, but still same test errors. (PS I do have Skype, that is the closest I know about chat.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `enum` value in my ActiveRecord (so just an integer in my table), then I decided to change it for a `reference`. After removing the column and adding the corresponding reference, I was getting the error for the tests. My mistake was that I forgot to add the `belongs_to :MODEL` in the model that the reference was added.